# How to use systemoption DETACH in SAS

Tags: sas, remote-access, remote-server

I am submitting a program remotely and I want to use the system option Detach. 
How can I use it?

```
option detach; 
rsubmit; 
proc sql ; 
create table X
as select * from Y
order by dd
; 
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the system option DETACH is application to OpenVMS OS only. Is that your OS on the SAS server?

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostvms/62450/HTML/default/viewer.htm#alp-sysops-detach.htm

May be you want to rephrase your question? Like "How do I run this program asynchronously on Unix/Windows platform with rsubmit?"

Regards,
Vasilij